# Foreman provisioning stuck in "Pending Installation" 409 Conflict on all installs

Tags: foreman, provisioning

I'm testing Foreman but all the VMs I've created get stuck in a boot loop unless I manually disable PXE boot.  In the UI i see the machine as "Pending Installation" even after the puppet agent reports in.  From the log file I've verified that the token has been passed back to Foreman, but it always gets a 409 error and doesn't seem to update. Not sure what I'm missing

Example:

```
[I] Started GET "/unattended/built?token=dd4c92e9-311d-49df-a5dd-1d8ad446ba2a" for 192.168.x.x 
[I] Processing by UnattendedController#built as */*
[I]   Parameters: {"token"=>"dd4c92e9-311d-49df-a5dd-1d8ad446ba2a"}
[I] Found test13.example.com
[I] unattended: test13.example.com is Built!
[I] Completed 409 Conflict in 156ms (ActiveRecord: 18.3ms)
```

The goal is to have the machines start and attempt to PXE then move on to the HDD unless a job has been set up for them.

Any help on this would be much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When 409 Conflict is returned, the Foreman production.log contains this warning:

```
Failed to set Build on HOST NAME: error message
```

Search the log for this message.